# Wxpython : Link '+' to the tab function when typed inside cell?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxgrid

Can some one please help me with this?
The Keycode for '+' is 388
The Keycode for '/t' is 9

I've tried many ways and I can't seem to figure this out.

Goal: Say we have a 4x4 grid and I am at position (col,row) (1,2), if I type 123.4 and then press enter on the numpad, the computer will enter 123.4 at position (1,2) and will go to next row which will be position (1,3).

Now, I want a similar thing to happen in where if I am at position (col,row) (1,2), if I type 123.4 and then press '+' on the numpad, the computer will enter 123.4 at position (1,2) and will go to next col which will be position (2,2).

Answer (score 0):

You may get some traction with `wx.UIActionSimulator`

try something like:
bind whatever with

```
whatever.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.go)

def go(self, event):
    key = event.GetKeyCode()
    if key == 388: # numeric pad + character
        key = 370  # numeric pad Enter or whatever you require
        act = wx.UIActionSimulator()
        act.Char(key, modifiers=wx.MOD_NONE)
        print("post")
        return
    event.Skip()
```

`Skip` is essential to allow the key event to be processed, when it isn't equal to 388